# Does the foreign key slow down the join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have two databases **test** & **test2**. Both have the same tables(employees & salaries) and both have the same records. **test2** database uses a foreign key and **test** database doesn't.

### test structure

```
test.employees
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

test.salaries
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| salary | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| emp_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### test2 structure

```
test2.employees
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

test2.salaries
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| salary | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| emp_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I run the same join query on both databases

```
select * from employees inner join salaries on employees.emp_id=salaries.emp_id;
```

This is the output i get from **test** database which doesn't contain a foreign key

```
2844047 rows in set (3.25 sec)
```

This is the output i get from **test2** database which contains a foreign key

```
2844047 rows in set (17.21 sec)
```

So does the foreign key slow down the join query?

Comment: Compare the execution plans!

Comment: Is salaries.emp_id indexed in either database? Creating a foreign key won't automatically index the child table column. The FK constraint just prevents you from deleting parent rows.

Comment: @DonSeiler I created an index and executed the same query. The time increased to 24.93 sec.

Answer (score 4):

Your empirical evidence suggests that in at least one case it does.  So, if we believe your numbers, the answer is clearly "yes" -- and I assume you have ruled out other potential causes such as locks on the table or resource competition (actually the difference is pretty big).  I presume that you want to know why.

In most databases, declaring a foreign key is about relational integrity.  It would have no effect on the optimization of queries.  The `join` conditions in the query would redundantly cover the same information.

However, MySQL does a bit more when a foreign key is declared.  A foreign key declaration automatically creates an index on the columns being used.  This is not standard behavior -- I'm not even sure if any other database does this.

Normally, an index would *benefit* performance.  In this case, the optimizer has more choices on how to approach the query.  For whatever reason, it is using a substandard execution plan.

You should be able to look at the `explain` plans and see a difference.  The issue is that the optimizer has chosen the wrong plan.  I would say that this is uncommon and should not dissuade you from using proper foreign key declarations in your databases.